# AddressSanitizer provoking crash on MacOS Mojave with Chromium Embedded Framework

Tags: xcode, macos, chromium-embedded, address-sanitizer

I'm trying to use ASan to debug code of my plugin (dynamic library) running in a big 3rd party host app which is using Juce and Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF).
It works fine on MacOS 10.11 (El Capitan) and XCode 8, but the very same app on a new MacBook with MacOS 10.14 (Mojave) and either XCode 9 or 11 first stops with `EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0)` and then crashes with `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)` in

```
  * frame #0: 0x000000011768fe78 Chromium Embedded Framework`___lldb_unnamed_symbol167560$$Chromium Embedded Framework + 88
    frame #1: 0x000000011768fba5 Chromium Embedded Framework`___lldb_unnamed_symbol167550$$Chromium Embedded Framework + 37
    frame #2: 0x00007fff5c522c99 libsystem_malloc.dylib`malloc_zone_malloc + 103
    frame #3: 0x00007fff5c524191 libsystem_malloc.dylib`malloc_set_zone_name + 84
    frame #4: 0x00000001011d9d2d libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib`wrap_malloc_set_zone_name + 173
    frame #5: 0x0000000102002f1b libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 8
    frame #6: 0x0000000102004ba9 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_once_callout + 87
    frame #7: 0x00007fff3ae6132d QuartzCore`get_malloc_zone(unsigned long) + 43
    frame #8: 0x00007fff3ae6157a QuartzCore`CA::Transaction::set_disable_actions(bool) + 44
    frame #9: 0x00007fff2da3f5a0 AppKit`-[NSView _updateLayerBackedness] + 414
    frame #10: 0x00007fff2da2555e AppKit`-[NSView didChangeValueForKey:] + 65
    frame #11: 0x00000001007e6550 Max`juce::NSViewComponentPeer::NSViewComponentPeer(juce::Component&, int, NSView*) + 640
    frame #12: 0x00000001007e62a2 Max`juce::Component::createNewPeer(int, void*) + 50
```

I'm at a loss here even just about whether the problem lies in MacOS, ASan, CEF, Juce, or the host App.
I also tried to avoid interception of the functions above via ASan's suppression list, but never got it to work. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By default Chromium builds on Mac have allocator shim enabled which overwrites malloc zones and causes issues with ASAN. To disable it you have to build from sources with GN option `use_allocator_shim=false`.

Alternatively you can build Chromium with `is_asan=true` option to enable ASAN.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I'm afraid Chromium is part of the (copy protected) 3rd party app, so I'm not sure how to make it use a self-built chromium (via DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES, maybe)?

Comment: @diemo If they use default CEF binaries downloaded from https://cef-builds.spotifycdn.com/index.html then you can make the same CEF build from sources with allocator shim disabled or asan enabled and replace binaries in that third party app. CEF dll library has a version number information embedded, so that you can check which commit exactly it uses, so you can build exact same version.

Comment: Hmm, otool reports version 801.0.2 while official cef is at 86 `@executable_path/../Frameworks/Chromium Embedded Framework.framework/Chromium Embedded Framework (compatibility version 801.0.2, current version 801.0.2)`

Comment: The other mystery is that the same 3rd party app, with the same CEF inside, works on MacOS 10.11.

Comment: dylib version `801.0.2` translates to CEF version `80.1.2`. You can find it here: https://cef-builds.spotifycdn.com/index.html#macosx64:80.1.2 (Applied version filter, see All builds at the bottom).

Comment: Note that this still doesn't specify CEF commit, so I don't know if the binaries in third party app were not custom built (patched etc.). But you can verify it by downloading CEF binaries from Spotify and checking it MD5 hash of the file and compare it with the third party app binary.

Answer (score 0):

If none of your objects need this, I just discovered that you can actually entirely remove "Chromium Embedded Framework.framework" from said app's frameworks and things will still work ; this allows me to debug my externals with asan / ubsan :-)